# setting instance variable in class Customer __init__ from main()

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to set an instance variable from the main function. Within the class Customer I have created the **init**(). 
self.__email = email
In the main function, I am trying to set the email for 2 separate objects equal to an input within the main function.
I have initialized the objects in main, I just cannot seem to find/ figure out how to create 2 separate emails for the 2 separate objects established in the main function.

```
from customer import Customer
def main():

    customer1 = Customer('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'card_number', 'security_code')
    customer2 = Customer('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'card_number', 'security_code')
    customer1.email = input("Enter email address:") # trying to set email in __init__ (for class Customer)for customer1 equal to the input
    customer1.input_info()
    customer1.verify_info()
    customer2.email = input("Enter email address:")
    customer2.input_info()
    customer2.verify_info()
    file1 = open("customers.txt", "a")
    file1.write(customer1.output_info())
    file1.write(customer2.output_info())

main()
class Customer:
def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, email, password, card_number, security_code):
    self.__firstname = firstname
    self.__lastname = lastname
    self.__age = 0
    self.__email = email
    self.__password = password
    self.__card_number = card_number
    self.__security_code = security_code
```

Results should be setting the email for customer1 and customer2 equal to the input within the main function. Then writing it into a text file.
The actual results are printing "email" in the text file, instead of the input.

Comment: Please post the source code of the `Customer` object.

Comment: ok. Sorry for the format. I believe I have remedied that.

Comment: Don't use `__`-prefixed names for names you want to access outside of an instance method.

Comment: Why not call `input` *first*, then pass its return value as the `email` argument to `Customer.__init__`?

Comment: the problem you assigned value to `email` but the actual attribute in your class is `__email`, try this `customer1.__email = input("Enter email address:")` and see how it goes, note: you need to fix your attributes names

Comment: @MahmoudElshahat That won't work due to the name mangling Python applies to `__`-prefixed attribute names.

Comment: Ah. Yes. That works, and it makes sense. Thank you for that @chepner

Comment: There are 2 separate objects to create the email for. If I get the input of an email prior to, won't it set the input email for both objects? customer1 and customer 2.

Answer (score 2):

Try using setattr. Example:

```py
mail = input("Enter email address:")
setattr(customer1, 'email', mail)
```